# A generalization of the Clifford algebra

Tags: reference-request, spin-geometry, clifford-algebras

Let $(E,g)$ be a vector space with a symmetric bilinear form, and $a,b$ be two endomorphisms of $E$. The generalized Clifford algebra is defined by the free algebra of $E$ with quotient by the relations: $$ a(e). b(f)+a(f).b(e)=(-g(a(e),b(f))-g(a(f),b(e)))1$$
with $e,f$ in $E$. Can I find a generalized spinors space over a "spin" manifold $M$? Can I have a Dirac operator (with $b=1$)?